# Function invocation in for loop does not fail even with "set -e"

Tags: bash

Consider the following simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

gen() {
  seq 0 3
}

for c in $(gen); do
  echo c
done

echo "finish"
```

It has `set -e` set, so when something fails, it is supposed to just exit with a non-zero exit code.

It will call `gen` function and prints the output of `seq 0 3`, will print `finish` and exit with code=0.

If I modify `gen` to fail, say, by invoking `seqqq` command (which doesn't exist) instead:

```
$ ./script.sh; echo $?
./script.sh: line 6: seqqq: command not found
finish
0
```

It prints the error message from the sub-shell, it doesn't fail right away and exit (with a non-zero code) immediately as `set -e` is supposed to do; it keeps executing and exits with code=0.

What is the explanation behind this? Note, if I just replace with my for loop as this, it fails as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

gen() {
  seqqq 0 3
}

gen # <-- fails and exits here with code=127

echo "finish"
```

Comment: Take a look at [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: `set -u` isn't without its caveats either -- see [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). Short form: There is no silver bullet to writing reliable shell scripts; and if there were, `set -eou pipefail` would *definitely* not be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `set -e` is ineffective in the context of command substitution, as in:

```
for c in $(gen); do
  echo c
done
```

However, `set -e` does work in the context of straight function invocation, as in:

```
gen
```

It is hard or near impossible to write reliable shell scripts with `set -e`.  Use explicit error handling instead.  You can read more about this here: [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *bashing* "strict mode" we could also adhere to executing loop commands before the loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e -E -u -o pipefail

shopt -s inherit_errexit

trap 's=$?; echo "$0: Error on line "$LINENO": $BASH_COMMAND"; exit $s' ERR
IFS=$'\n\t'

gen() {
  seqqq 0 3
}

cs=$(gen)
for c in $cs; do
  echo c
done

echo "finish"
```

This will stop when calling `cs=$(gen)`:

> line 10: seqqq: command not found
>
> Error on line 13: cs=$(gen)